# Notify user who run the build (if its broke) Teamcity

Tags: teamcity, teamcity-9.0

I have a TeamCity Enterprise 2019.2 (build 71499). Is it possible to notify user who run the build if it was broken via email? Cant find such option in Notification rules:
[image]

**Builds with my changes only** does not work for me, because the author of the changes often does not coincide with the author of the build. I need to notify ONLY author of build/release (person who run build/release) Is it possible to do this using standard TeamCity Notification rules? or maybe there is any other way to do what I need?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think it is possible out of the box. (might be worth creating a feature request)

There is a workaround that has worked for me:

1. Enable the "Add builds triggered by me to favorites" in the profile General settings.
   [image]
2. Set notification on "My favorite builds only"

This way I get notifications for the builds I directly hit 'run' on.

Comment: Works the same as described, thanks! Only one thing I'm worried about: there will be lots of builds in my "favorite builds" tab in few years. did it somehow affect the speed of teamcity in your case?

Comment: well, once in a while I do a cleanup there :) it probably could be scripted somehow.